# Jquery .is() class optional usage

Tags: jquery, html

When doing form validation, I encountered this code:

```
//check each input to ensure it isn't empty
$( "#frmReservation :input" ).each( function(i) {
    if($(this).val() == '' && !$(this).is('.optional'))
    {
        success = false;
    }
});
```

"optional" is a class that's defined on each input that's, well, optional.  The problem is that the optional clause is being ignored.  Each input is wrapped in a div, but I don't think that should matter.  Suggestions?

Comment: Post a fiddle at jsfiddle.net proving this failure.

Comment: Whoa, fiddle's new to me; thanks.  I saved time getting a working answer, but I'm gonna lose an hour playing with this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3eSQq/)

Comment: I'm a fool, and you're right, it does work.  My error was a typo in the form submit line.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this:

```
if(.. !$(this).hasClass('optional'))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using `if($(this).val() == '' && !$(this).hasClass('.optional'))`

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to this question. A better way is to check inputs on the fly when you focus out of an input. Inputs with class optional will not be counted.

```
$('input').not('.optional').blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length < 1) {
        $(this).addClass('error')
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('error')
    }
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/m6gdK/1/